# как скачать картинки с сервера по ссылкам програмно?

Tags: php

```
есть массив картинкок
$img = [
'https://images.com/1.jpg',
'https://images.com/2.jpg',
'https://images.com/3.jpg',
'https://images.com/4.jpg',
....
'https://images.com/1000.jpg'
]
```

как эти все картинки выкачать в определенную папку и чтобы сохранить их название т.е чтобы скачались 1.jpg, 2.jpg,3.jpg,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = 'images';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($img; $i++) {
  $name = explode('/', $img[$i];
  $name = end($name);
  file_put_contents($path.'/'.$name, file_get_contents($img[$i]));
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а чтобы выкачало на сайт нужно тут $path = 'images'; указать
$path = 'https://mysite.com/images'; ?

Comment: @Junior ну вы же и так с сайта скрипт запускаете? в path харнится директория куда загрузятся файлы относительно скрипта, который их качает. Если запускаете скрипт с корня сайта, оставьте в path images и тогда картинки будут на site/images

Comment: а вообще как считаете показывать на своем сайте картинки с другго сата по разрешению естественно, лучше по ссылкам или выкачать ?

Comment: @Junior нормально. Стак, например, хранит картинки на imgur`e. Вопрос только в том, насколько вы можете быть уверены, что тот сайт не закроется или не удалит картинки. Ну и по скорости запросов. Может он любит падать и не всегда картинки будут доходить. Я стараюсь у себя хранить, чтобы меньше зависеть от других сайтов.

Comment: @ Gelloiss спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать для этого библиотеку https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

```
$curl = new Curl\Curl();

$imageUrls = [
    'https://example.com/1.jpg',
    'https://example.com/2.jpg',
    'https://example.com/3.jpg',
    'https://example.com/4.jpg',
];

foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
    $curl->download($imageUrl, __DIR__ . '/YourFolder/' . basename($imageUrl));
}
```

Comment: спасибо , а чтобы выкачать картнки не на комп а в папку сайта сразу так возможно?